# Django transactions and concurrency

Tags: python, database, django, concurrency

I have a view that needs to perform updates to the database involving a shared resource that needs locking (the implementation is complex, but nothing more than a shared counter at heart).

To shield myself from race conditions, I'm using code that looks roughly like this:

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def do_it(request):
    affected_models = Something.objects.select_for_update(blah = 1)

    for model in affected_models:
        model.modify()
        model.save()

    transaction.commit()
```

Is this usage of `commit_manually`, `select_for_update()` and `save()` ok? How can I write a test that confirms this? I can't find, say, a signal that Django fires between transactions; and I can't just run it and hope concurrency issues arise and are dealt with.

Comment: Regarding testing Michael Foord wrote regarding a similar problem and it provides a [pattern for testing][1]. It uses subprocess.


  [1]: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2011_05_07.shtml

Comment: http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/05/26/testing-django-views-for-concurrency-issues/

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use `commit_on_success` there?

I think the query itself should look like:

```
Something.objects.select_for_update().filter(...)
```

I don't think django does anything special on `select_for_update` what you could assert on. Only assertion comes to my head is `assertTrue(queryset.query.select_for_update)`. It tests nothing and might be usefull only if somebody accidentaly(?) removes the call.

Even if you come up with some unit test for this run condition problem I don't think it would be wise to put that into the project.

Rather focus on testing your code, not the db behaviour.